# Evernote API: How to upload a note with pure ENML instead of plain text

Tags: ios, swift, api, evernote

I'm trying to set the content of a note to raw ENML but when I upload the note and then look at the note in the sandbox web app it looks like it is just treating the ENML as plain text. How do I upload a note with raw ENML so I can use all of the features in ENML? Here is the Swift code:

```
let note: ENNote = ENNote()
note.title = title


let testEmlString: String =
    "<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'utf-8'?>" +
    "<!DOCTYPE en-note SYSTEM\"http://xml.evernote.com/pub/enml2.dtd\">" +
    "<en-note>" +
      "<div><br /></div>" +
      "<div>" +
        "<span style=\"font-size: 18px;\">" +
          "<b>Hello World</b>" +
        "</span>" +
      "</div>" +
      "<div><br /></div>" +
   "</en-note>"

note.content = ENNoteContent(string: testEmlString)

ENSession.sharedSession().uploadNote(note, notebook: nil, completion: { noteRef, error in
 if error == nil {
      print("Note upload OK")
 } else {
      print("Upload note error: \(error)")
 }
})
```

I read in another posting that the ENNoteContent class has an extra constructor if I import the advanced header in my Bridging-Header.h file:

```
#import <ENSDK/ENSDK.h>
#import <ENSDK/Advanced/ENSDKAdvanced.h>
```

But this causes a compile time error in: ENSDKAdvanced.h saying:

```
ENSDK.h file not found
```

Hopefully someone can help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue.

Change the ENSDK import link as follows

`From "ENSDK.h" to <ENSDK/ENSDK.h>`

This will need to be changed in these files:

- ENSDKAdvanced.h
- ENNoteStoreClient.h
- ENSDKPrivate.h

That's it!